# Undefined index in codeigniter session

Tags: codeigniter, session

When I create a new User, I store in session the new e-mail like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('new_user', ['new_email', $data['email']]);
```

If I use `var_dump` on `$this->session->userdata('new_user')`, the result is the following:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "new_email" [1]=> string(24) "email@email.com" }

But when I try to access it to print the value, by echoing `$this->session->userdata('new_user')['new_email']`, an error saying the index `new_email` does not exist. I've used this way of printing values in my whole website, but specifically in this page, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $this->session->set_userdata('new_user',$data['email'])